# Magento 2.2.4 particular page cache disable using the observer OR any other method

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

I want to create observer for particular page cache disable.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the cache in a page marking any block of the page like `cacheable="false"`.
If any block of a page is marked as cacheable="false", the full page will have the cache disabled.

*To create an uncacheable page, mark any block on that page as uncacheable in the layout using cacheable="false".*
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html

An example here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/layout/paypal_payflow_returnurl.xml

If you want specify a cms page like no cacheable, you have to update the section **layout_update_xml** in the admin cms page and write this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

You have to be careful with this, because it affects the performance of the web.

Comment: Hello , one block call in cms page with cacheable="false" but that not working.... some other hints....

Comment: I can try , and call the block on cms page but not working, here see...{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.cart.page"   template="Custom_Custom::cmscart/cart_details.phtml" cacheable="false"}}, block call perfect but when i add to cart some products than new added product not display that page,when i clear cache than display ,means the cacheable="false" not Working

Comment: @RasikMiyani I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you mark as valid the answer?